# Combining repeating date/value pairs into single date/value pair

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a .csv with **date** and **ticket sales** columns. Dates are repeated to signify multiple sales in one day. Is there a way to combine the repeating dates into a single row with their respective values added?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrfDh.png)

Comment: Include your data in the post itself as text, not as an image. What did you do to try to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot.

This solution assumes the "ticket sales" column is a number (count of tickets sold in that transaction).

```
import pandas as pd ## Imports pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('your_csv_file.csv') ## reads your csv into a pandas dataframe
df = df.groupby(['date']).sum() ## combines duplicate values in the 'date' column into a single record, then provides a sum total of the values associated with sales on that date
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much! PS. Is there a way to then sort the dates in descending order?

Comment: df.sort_values(by=['date'], ascending=False) check out the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: Thanks again! Huge help.

Answer (score 1):

Without pandas here's an efficient approach using `itertools.groupby` and `operator.itemgetter` for the key:

```
ticket_counts = {dt: sum(int(q[1]) for q in qty)
                     for dt, qty in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0))}
```

Test data:

```
12/2/19,1
12/2/19,1
12/1/19,1
12/1/19,1
12/1/19,1
12/1/19,1
12/1/19,1
12/1/19,1
11/30/19,1
11/30/19,1
```

Results:

```
{'12/2/19': 2, '12/1/19': 6, '11/30/19': 2}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Love the compactness.

Answer (score 0):

I'll allow you to set up the code for `csv`, opening/reading your file. But I would use a dictionary with the dates as keys and cumulative ticket sales as the values.

```
d = {}

# Iterate through rows
for row in file:
    date = row[0]
    if date not in d:
         d[date] = row[1]    
    else:
        # The date is already in the dictionary then add num tickets sold
        d[date] += row[1]
```

This will scale if your num of ticket sales are not just 1.

Comment: That's a great solution. Thank you.

Comment: A defaultdict would make this even simpler.